# Map with rows in inverted order

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, leaflet

I download a few tiles from OpenStreetMap (only for testing purpose).
Then i use the fantastical Leaflet javascript framework to view the interactive map, but when i open the browser i see the horizontal (Y) tiles images in inverted order.
What's the problem here ?? I'm doing something wrong ??

Here is my code (is simple enough):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/core.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" /> 
    <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-23.13, -82.38], 14);
    L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        minZoom: 12,
        maxZoom: 16,
        attribution: 'SampleMap',
        tms: true
    }).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the resulting image is this (note that the rows are inverted). The expecting result is row 1,2,3 and are showed 3,2,1:

[image: Tiles showed with leaflet]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you try example with `http://tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` url? If all will look good then probably you storing tiles wrong.

Comment: @tbicr I use that url too, and still i'm getting the maps in inversed order, am i using the leaflet library wrong ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem persist when i use `http://tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, so i'm storing the tiles in the right way.
I solve the problem only by quitting the `tms: true` line, i read a lot of tutorials using it to process off-line maps.
Expect that helps to someone else.

Comment: Reading the reference (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) says that if tms is true, inverses Y axis numbering for tiles (turn this on for TMS services), so its actually working as intended if you set it to true

Comment: @Xavi Fair enough, i check that 2 days after. Please be free to edit the answer.